# Form does not show its nested attribute block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have a form that deals with nested attributes (I think).

A `project` has_many `graphs`, through `project_graph`.

In my form, the block of code for the nested attribute never is rendered. Any ideas?

**View**

```
<%= form_for(@project, :html => { class: :form }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :project_user_graphs do |graph_form| %> <!-- this never renders -->
       <p>How come this block never is executed? This wont show up.</p>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**Models**

```
class UserGraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_user_graphs
  has_many :projects, through: :project_user_graph
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_user_graphs, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['user_graph_id'].blank?}
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_user_graphs
  has_many :user_graphs, through: :project_user_graph
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_user_graphs, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['user_graph_id'].blank?}
end
```

Comment: Maybe there are no instances of the association. In your controller did you do something like `@project.project_user_graphs.build`?

Answer (score 0):

Aceofspades is correct, fields_for will create fields for each existing item - it won't create fields for an item which doesn't exist yet. Basically what's going on is your @project has no project_user_graphs yet. If you add:

```
<%= f.fields_for :project_user_graphs, @project.project_user_graphs.new do |g| %>
```

It will create a new graph for you on the spot and then show the field. However this isn't typically what you want to do - instead, you want to create the project_user_graph in the controller:

```
@project.project_user_graphs.build
```

Or if you're certain that every project will have a project_user_graph you can use a callback in the Project.rb model to create one every time a project is created.